# how to create javascript library for self-written functions

Tags: javascript

---

**    want to call common js for all validation for 20 jsp f**

```
function mAbcRefresher(refresh, refreshTime) {
//function code
}
function QWERTY(address){
//function code
}
function ASDF(address, value, refreshCallback){....
........
........
........`
```

---

I just copy these functions to a JS file and include the JS file in my html document. i need some standard way to write this type of validation code

Comment: Questions like _"Will it work if..."_ are usually answered by just giving it a try.

Comment: Yes, it will work.

Comment: i think there are some stranded pattern to make function in js file.I want to know that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Firstly created that common file eg. common.js. Add it to all your jsp pages. The standered way to write the code in js file

```
//common.js file
                  var  common={ 
    //function name      
      formvalidation   :  function(){
    //eg.you want to get all   required parts 
    var elements=$("input:visible, select:visible , textarea:visible");

      $.each($(elements) function( index, element ){
    //you can get do your code.
        $(element).attr("attr");

                                                    });

            }

    //check condition and return false or true
            }
```

---

above coders for write common functions.
now in jsp to call the function 
Add this js file to head

then you can call the function in jsp
like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//will return true or false
if(common.formvalidation()){

//submit or not
}
});
```

you can call another function inside this formvalidation() function

just you have assign a variable for this function

```
    var  common={ 
        //function name      
          formvalidation   :  function(){
    var date=this;
       var result=date.formDate();
    }


formDate   :  function(){
    // do your code
    }

}
```

You can look above code for the idea. definitely it will be helpful for you

Comment: You are asking and then answering your own question. Any specific reason?

Comment: Actually i recently i  got the ans. So i thought that i should share the my answer. Might be i can get more better ans.That's why i gave anwer